# After Installing Magento 2.4.1 And Configuration, Finally I Get This Error

Tags: php, magento2

I found that it is very difficult to install and configure magento2.4.1 version. After a lot of effort, I managed to get to this point where I get an error related to cookies. Can anybody please help me?

**Error is reproduced below**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor, setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, array given

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor, setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, array given
#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...'), 'Magento\Framewor...', NULL, 'session', 'Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\Framewor...', array('session', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#5 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Framewor...', array(array('mathRandom', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('session', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('escaper', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#6 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewor...', array(array('mathRandom', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('session', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('escaper', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...'), 'Magento\Framewor...', NULL, 'formKey', 'Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#10 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\Framewor...', array('formKey', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#11 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Framewor...', array(array('formKey', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewor...', array(array('formKey', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:170]
#15 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...'), 'Magento\Framewor...', NULL, 'formKeyValidator', 'CsrfRequestValid...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#16 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('CsrfRequestValid...', array('formKeyValidator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#17 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('CsrfRequestValid...', array(array('formKeyValidator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('redirectFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('appState', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#18 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('CsrfRequestValid...', array(array('formKeyValidator', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('redirectFactory', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false), array('appState', 'Magento\Framewor...', true, NULL, false)), array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#19 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('CsrfRequestValid...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#20 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('CsrfRequestValid...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:206]
#21 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...'))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:182]
#22 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')), NULL, NULL, 'validators', 'RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:276]
#23 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('RequestValidator', array('validators', NULL, true, NULL, false), array('validators' => array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:239]
#24 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('RequestValidator', array(array('validators', NULL, true, NULL, false)), array('validators' => array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34]
#25 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('RequestValidator', array(array('validators', NULL, true, NULL, false)), array('validators' => array('csrf_validator' => array('instance' => 'CsrfRequestValid...'), 'http_method_vali...' => array('instance' => 'Magento\Framewor...')))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59]
#26 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#27 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('RequestValidator') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:86]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#000000002ddc016a00000000179c2cee#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002ddc075100000000179c2cee#, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:14]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->__construct(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#000000002ddc016a00000000179c2cee#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002ddc075100000000179c2cee#, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#30 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array(&Magento\Framework\App\RouterList#000000002ddc016a00000000179c2cee#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000002ddc075100000000179c2cee#, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#31 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#32 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewor...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:115]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000002ddc073c00000000179c2cee#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved. It was an issue with php version. I had php 7.4 in my machine, but it was not enabled. I did this to make 7.4 default.

**disabled the existing version**
sudo a2dismod php7.2
systemctl restart apache2
**enabled the new version**
sudo a2enmod php7.4
systemctl restart apache2

Finally I saw the homepage!

Comment: This is what fixed it for me. I had to make sure 7.4 was running in terminal AND nginx (even though m2 docs say to use php 7.2?? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html). Terminal I used brew to configure, NGINX I needed to add this to 'default' in sites-enabled (adding elsewhere it complained about duplicate declarations)  "upstream fastcgi_backend { server 127.0.0.1:9074; }".